# Using rest of stream after Stream.take(1)

Tags: elixir

I'm using a library to read a csv file which returns a stream of rows:

```
File.stream!("some_file.csv")
|> CSV.decode  # returns a stream of rows
```

The first row is usually the csv header, so I thought it would be cool to split header and body:

```
def split_header_and_body(row_stream) do
  header = row_stream |> Stream.take(1) |> Enum.to_list |> List.first
  body = row_stream |> Stream.drop(1)

  {header, body}
end
```

This doesn't work, probably because `Stream.take/1` ends enumeration (as stated in the docs).

I thought everything is immutable, so I can just reuse the initial `row_stream`, but this is not the case and I couldn't find out how to duplicate the stream either.

Comment: IO streams may not yield the same result when you iterate them multiple times! Think for example stdin, there is no way to replay that.

Comment: I understand that, but I still think it should be possible to take one element and return the rest of the stream to do something with it. Kind of like [head | tail] matching.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.  I believe the issue is that you want to call Enum.to_list on body before returning it, otherwise you're returning a Stream, which may not be what you intend.

The Stream itself is immutable.  In fact, you could do

```
row_stream | > Stream.take(1) |> Enum.to_list |> IO.inspect
```

and immediately call

```
row_stream | > Stream.take(5) |> Enum.to_list |> IO.inspect
```

And you'll see the truth of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undertand why you say "it does not work". I have tried your code and it works.

In fact Streams are inmutable, in the documentation says

> Lazily takes the next count elements from the enumerable and stops enumeration

Meaning that the resulting stream is stoped, not the original one which remains unchanged

Anyway I've done another version of your code, I think it is more simple

```
def split_header_and_body(row_stream) do
  {Enum.at(row_stream,0), Stream.drop(row_stream,1)}
end
```